# How to prove two suprema are equal

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Is the following equation correct? How to prove.

$$
\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|=\sup \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}
$$

Thanks!

Comment: Singular: supremum; plural: suprema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x \neq 0$ the vector $y=\frac 1 {\|x||} x$ has norm $1$, and $\frac {\|Ax\|} {\|x\|}=\|Ay\|$ by linearity. So RHS $\leq $ LHS. The other inequality is obvious.